# Why did i get blocked

Tags: discussion

Why I get block for trying to ask a simple question and when I dislike there answer because the question  and keep telling me to do what I told them I already have done  and had nothing to do with the question then took Lee all last night going threw ky.gov and found the answer just to tell them I found it and it's a law I mean and it's My answer but I get deleted and they get all likes and keep that they answer it and go ahead I got it screenshot all of it because seems like some people can answer wrong and still be right but someone can be right and there still wrong because I'm not someone special can't get no real answer here trust me I'm put this everywhere I know lots of people  it was cool I dint ever care she or they answer it wrong I was nice but I really found and proved an wrong that's when I got deleted

Comment: I guarantee you that a major reason for the downvotes is that your posts are extremely difficult to read. Please slow down and format them in sentences and paragraphs and you will get a much better reception.

Comment: Please punctuate your question with full stops and commas, etc. It helps others follow what you're trying to say.

Comment: See meta stackoverflow's question on the subject: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 5):

The system blocks you automatically when you post questions or answers that get lots of downvotes. People can downvote for lots of reasons and moderators don't control that, but I'd guess it was because you posted the same question repeatedly and it was hard to understand.

I think you've probably got as much help as you're likely to get from this site, which is really focused on financial management and not difficult legal disputes.